# Best location for breadcrumb in a blog

Tags: breadcrumbs

Are breadcrumbs still necessary based on current UX trends?

So for my site: for a single blog post, the level would be `Home > Parent Category > Child Category > Blog Post`. If I were to put such breadcrumb on top of the blog post, it would look redundant because all child categories are in my navigation bar.

Or should I just place a `"Back to 'Child Category'"` below (and on top?) of the blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how visible your child navigation is. While Breadcrumbs can be redundant in some cases, they do serve as a medium of quick navigation as well.

To quote this article [Breadcrumb Navigation Examined: Best Practices & Examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/breadcrumb-navigation-examined-best-practices-examples/)

> Fact of the matter is, breadcrumb navigation will greatly increase the
>   usability of a website. Breadcrumbs give users an alternative method
>   of navigation, allow them to see where they stand in the hierarchy of
>   a website, and will reduce the number of steps needed to navigate to a
>   higher-level within a website.

This article from smashing Magazine [Breadcrumbs In Web Design: Examples And Best Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/) has this to say :

> Here are just some of the benefits of using a breadcrumb trail.
>
> **Convenient for users** Breadcrumbs are used primarily to give users a secondary means of navigating a website. By offering a breadcrumb
>   trail for all pages on a large multi-level website, users can navigate
>   to higher-level categories more easily.
>
> **Reduces clicks or actions to return to higher-level pages**
>
> Instead of using the browser’s “Back” button or the website’s primary
>   navigation to return to a higher-level page, users can now use the
>   breadcrumbs with a fewer number of clicks.
>
> **Doesn’t usually hog screen space**.
>
> Because they’re typically horizontally oriented and plainly styled,
>   breadcrumb trails don’t take up a lot of space on the page. The
>   benefit is that they have little to no negative impact in terms of
>   content overload, and they outweigh any negatives if used properly.
>
> **Reduces bounce rates** Breadcrumb trails can be a great way to entice first-time visitors to peruse a website after having viewed the
>   landing page. For example, say a user arrives on a page through a
>   Google search, seeing a breadcrumb trail may tempt that user to click
>   to higher-level pages to view related topics of interests. This, in
>   turn, reduces the overall website bounce rate.

Comment: Do you have your personal say (or another source) on "Back to Parent Page" links?